# Getting my $_POST select option selected on submit

Tags: php, forms

This is part of a survey, where I´m having trouble with my date option. I have tested, that the value actually gets saved into the $_POST array when i submit, but i can't get it to preselect that value once it´s submitted. Hope someone can help me.

```
<pre>
$day=’’;
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['day']))
    {
        $day = $_POST['day'];
    }


$dayhtml='<select name="day">';
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
{
    if($day==$i)
    {
        $dayhtml.="<option value='$i' selected>$i</option>";
    }
    else
    {
        $dayhtml.="<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
    }
}

$dayhtml.='</select>';
echo $dayhtml;
</pre>
```

Comment: one `closing curly brace` is missing...

Comment: Sorry about that, i just pasted the snippets of code that was relevant to the question.

Comment: Do you get any output at all? Is just the preselection not working or the output in general?

Comment: Take a look at syntax errors, which I've mentioned. if `$_POST['submit']` exists script will work, I've tested !

Comment: I get the output correct, but i just don't get the value selected after submit.

Comment: @user2469206 is your dropdown is under submit section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, it seems that you have a missing closing brace for the `if (isset($_POST['submit']) { }` block which might be causing issues. Using `$day=0` helps clarify the code as well.

Also better to put your strings in single quotes

```
    $day=0;
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      if(isset($_POST['day']))
      {
        $day = $_POST['day'];
      }
    } # <!-- missing closing brace

    $dayhtml='<select name="day">';
    for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
    { 
      if($day==$i)
      {
        $dayhtml.= '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
      }
      else
      {
        $dayhtml.='<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
      }
    }
    $dayhtml.='</select>';
    echo $dayhtml;
```

Comment: Thank´s for noticing. As i mention in an above comment, i´ve just pasted the snippets of code that was relevant to the question, that´s why i was missing a bracket and my day was wrong. Want to point out, that my code is working so far, that im getting my select list with all the dates, but somehow my if($day==$i) isn´t working, cause when i view my source code after submitting, i can see in my print_r, that my value is saved in the post array, but the selected option is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Sorry, missed your updates. I've put the exact block of code above into a php script and it works as expected, see http://dorianmoore.com/stackoverflow/22345898.php for working copy. Is it possible that your issue is in the greater context of your code; in your real code are you setting `$dayhtml` there, but echoing it later? (also, to check it's not a browser issue, if you view source on the submitted page is the 'selected' value definitly not set?)

Comment: Im echoing the $dayhtml right after, and when i search for selected on the source, there is nothing. Maybe the issue is in the other code as you mentioned, but what should i look for?

Comment: that's very odd. I thought it might be getting over-written or hidden. You could try `if ( (int)$day == $i )` to force $day to be an integer, but if you code is exactly as is then that should make no difference. When you do  if you add `echo "[$day]"` what value comes between the square brackets?

Comment: I finally got i working. It´s was my other code that caused the issue. Everybody thanks so much for the help. i realize it´s hard trying to help me, when i had some other errors in my code, so sorry for all the confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing $day first and check if its value is coming as 01 or 1 or 02 or 2 and you are comparing with 1 and 2 etc.

If this is not the case then cast $i into string as $i is numeric and what is coming in $_POST['day'] is string. Though php is loosely coupled but sometimes it creates a problem.

Also it will be good if you put code for day also. How are have taken input for day.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I´ve tried converting §i to a string like you suggested, but i still can't get it selected.  $dayhtml='<select name="day">';
    for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
    {
        if($day==strval($i)) {
            $dayhtml.="<option value='$i' selected>$i</option>";
        }
        else
        {
            $dayhtml.="<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
        }
    }

Comment: I have postet all the code relevant to my §day, so i´m a bit confused about your last comment on how i´ve taken input for day?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does work after adding in the missing brace which should be just before this line:

```
$dayhtml='<select name="day">';
```

Please post all of your html and make sure that your submit button has the name 'submit'.

The below works just fine for me:

```
$day = 0;
if(isset($_POST['day']))
    $day = $_POST['day'];

$dayhtml='<form method="post"><select name="day">';
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
{
    $selected = ($day == $i) ? 'selected' : '';
    $dayhtml.= '<option value="'.$i.'" '.$selected.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}

$dayhtml.='</select><input type="submit" /></form>';

echo $dayhtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've syntax errors, try with following code:

```
$day=''; // take a look here, '' instead ``
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   if( isset($_POST['day']) )
    {
        $day = $_POST['day'];
    }


    $dayhtml='<select name="day">';
    for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
    {
        if($day==$i) {
            $dayhtml.='<option value="' . $i . '" selected="selected">' . $i . '</option>';
        }
        else
        {
            $dayhtml.='<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
        }
    }

    $dayhtml.='</select>';
    echo $dayhtml;
} // missing `}` here
```

**NOTE:** When you are writing `html` code in `php` it is a good practice to wrap attributes in double quotes instead of single ones

Comment: The missing curly braces is probably due to the part of the code copied, he just didn't put there. As var he said so.

Comment: @Fabio OP has also backticks error `` in `$day` variable

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, i wrote the syntax wrong when i posted this, but it´s working correct in my document.

Comment: @user2469206 Did you take a look at updated one, I've in consideration  `selected="selected"` ?

Comment: @user2469206 Have you checked it ?

Comment: Thanks i´ve tried that crypticous. But my problem is, when i look at the source after i've submitted, the selected="selected" does not apaer anywhere in my code, so i'm guessing there is a fault in my if($day==$i)

Comment: I´ve just pasted the snippets of code that was relevant to the question, that´s why i was missing a bracket and my day was wrong. I want to point out, that my code is working so far, that im getting my select list with all the dates, but somehow my if($day==$i) isn´t working, cause when i view my source code after submitting, i can see in my print_r, that my value is saved in the post array, but the selected option is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I've tested it and it's working, did you check in your html output if `selected` is written ?

Comment: It´s not, thats why it´s so confusing.

Comment: It is far more likely your issue is with your html form code and in particular the submit button. There is no real need for the isset($_POST['submit']) in this example ... please see my answer.

Comment: @user2469206 For testing purpose try it without submitting and see the result

Comment: Hi Boreded, i´ve tried your code, working fine, but i still don´t get my value selected. After submit, i can see in print_r($_POST), that the value is saved in my §day, but still no selected.

Comment: @user2469206 If you are just refreshing page, try to close tab and then visit link again (not refresh current page)

Comment: Can you update your answer to show us what you currently now have and include as much as you can please. The code works so there is likely to be a very small issue elsewhere being overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `$day=’’;` with `$day=0`..
and your problem will be solved. I checked it on my pc...

the `commas` you used are not proper...

Comment: Yeah i got the code working too now, but the only thing wrong is the if($day==$i), cause i can't get the value selected

Comment: try using `$day = intval($_POST['day']);`... may be it is taking as a `string`...

Comment: Thanks Nishant, I tried using intval, but i´m still not getting it selected :(